# Error trying to get a pixmap from a texture (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a texture that comes right out of a FrameBuffer via getColorBufferTexture() method. The texture is fine, though vertically flipped as expected, I can draw it in a batch without problems.

I am trying to add it to a PixmapPacker because I want to save it for further use, but I am getting an exception ***"This TextureData implementation does not return a Pixmap"*** that I do not know how to overcome.

This is the code involved in the crash:

```
    if (!frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture().getTextureData().isPrepared())
        frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture().getTextureData().prepare();
    packer.pack("panel_cells", frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture().getTextureData().consumePixmap());
```

As you see, I've tried calling prepare() first, but it turned out the texture is always prepared at this point (hence the "if" first), so that's not the problem. Anyway I have left those two lines of code there just in case...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've finally solved this issue by overriden the following method when creating the FrameBuffer:

```
FrameBuffer frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, bufferSize, bufferSize, false) {
        @Override
        protected Texture createColorTexture() {
            PixmapTextureData data = new PixmapTextureData(new Pixmap(width, height, format), format, false, false);
            Texture result = new Texture(data);
            result.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
            result.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge, Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
            return result;
        }
    };
```

Now I am having problems with the packer, but that's a different story... at least I can get the texture.

Comment: Nah, this doesn't work actually. I got rid of the exception, but the consumePixmap() method seems not to be working as expected: whilst the texture returned by frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture works fine, if you do a new Texture(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture().getTextureData().consumePixmap()) you'll end up apparently with an empty texture, that makes no sense at all and, anyway, is useless.